# Xamarin.Android - Custom RecyclerView with grouping header

Tags: c#, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to create a custom recyclerView to have grouping section.

I use Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross, and I saw [this repo](https://github.com/thefex/MvvmCross/blob/0c2051254916f73101c7773b270c7b983bfec0d0/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments/Example.Droid/Resources/layout/fragment_example_recyclerview.axml) to make a RecyclerView with Grouping.

Well, I copy all his files, and tried to compile my solution (because I must to use MVVMCross v5.0.5):

[image: My project]

I made this simple page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidapp.controls.MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_recyclerviewexample"
            MvxHeaderLayoutId="@layout/recyclerviewexample_header"
            MvxFooterLayoutId="@layout/recyclerviewexample_footer"
            MvxHidesHeaderIfEmpty="true"
            MvxHidesFooterIfEmpty="true"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemSelected"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

But I have this error when my page is displayed:

> {Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class MvxRecyclerView ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "android.view.MvxRecyclerView" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.AndroidApp-1/base.a…}

And

> {Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.MvxRecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.AndroidApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.AndroidApp-1/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.compa…}

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** : Now I have this error (I have updated my axml code):

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.   at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve[TService]
>   () [0x00006] in
>   C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Mvx.cs:33    at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current[T]
>   () [0x00000] in
>   C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\BindingContext\MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.cs:23
>   at
>   MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current
>   () [0x00000] in
>   C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\BindingContext\MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.cs:17
>   at AndroidApp.Controls.MvxRecyclerAdapter..ctor () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/Projects/AndroidApp/AndroidApp/Controls/MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs:34
>   at AndroidApp.Controls.MvxRecyclerView..ctor (Android.Content.Context
>   context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/Projects/AndroidApp/AndroidApp/Controls/MvxRecyclerView.cs:16
>   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:1d68a509-a758-45e2-be4d-f4a51a401ff5 (intptr,object[])
>   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv,
>   System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr
>   signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr)
>   [0x000de] in :0 }

Comment: Never got this error but found something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864211/error-inflating-mvx-mvximageview).

Answer (score 3):

It says `Didn't find class "android.view.MvxRecyclerView"`, but the real location is different. You can add your namespace or the MvvmCross one to the AndroidViewAssemblies in the `Setup.cs`.

You should add something like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new 
List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
{
    typeof(MvxRecyclerView).Assembly
};
```

Comment: Ok fixed with namespace, but now I have this error (check my original post)

Comment: Try to "Clean" and "Rebuild" the project. That helped me with a similar error.

Comment: So how does your MvxRecyclerAdapter look like?

Comment: @Martijn00 I can share my project: https://ufile.io/i9gnu
MvxRecyclerAdapter was made by TheFex: https://github.com/thefex/MvvmCross/blob/f495bb98e1f7051e50249a15bce528824e9b81d7/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView/MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs

Comment: Don't use download sites like that. Either put it up on Github, but better just include the code here.

Comment: @Martijn00 Still have different problems.